# Converting 32 bit bmp to 24 bit

Tags: c#, .net, image, bmp

I have a System.Drawing.Image screenshot file.
I cast it to bmp, but the problem is that it makes a 32 bit bmp, while I need a 24 bit one. How can I convert it to 24?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this code:

```
public static Bitmap ConvertTo24bpp(Image img) {
  var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
  using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
  return bmp;
}
```