# how to make Image save as a 24-bit image?

Tags: c#, bitmap, save, 24-bit

How do I get C# to force bitmap images that are saved to be saved as 24-bit images as can be seen when you get the right-click properties of the image in Windows. All the images I save are set to 32-bit. I tried the below code with no luck. The source images are all 24-bit as well but are always saved as 32-bit image

```
    public void Save(int index)
    {

        string savestrFilename;
         SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();

        dialog.Title = "image save...";
        dialog.OverwritePrompt = true;
        dialog.Filter = "JPEG File(*.jpg)|*.jpg|Bitmap File(*.bmp)|*.bmp";

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            savestrFilename = dialog.FileName;
            System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(savestrFilename , System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.QualityLevel = 70;
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(_grabImageList[index].BitmapImage));
            encoder.Save(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate image file with low bit depths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483014/generate-image-file-with-low-bit-depths)

Comment: The currently stored bitmap bit is 8 bits.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate. This code to me suggests the use of a System.Windows.Media.BitmapImage, rather than System.Drawing.Bitmap. The solution from the referenced question may not be applicable to this use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting 32 bit bmp to 24 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572352/converting-32-bit-bmp-to-24-bit)

Comment: [Converting 32 bit bmp to 24 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572352/converting-32-bit-bmp-to-24-bit)